# How can I align the footer so it is generally centered at the bottom of the page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer

I am completely new to using Latex and I am trying to set up the basic layout of a document. I want to have a footer that has my name in the left part of the footer, some text in the center of the footer and the page number on the right part of the footer.

I have figured how to reduce the margins of the whole page but in doing so, the whole footer has shifted to the left. I want the footer to be centered so that it takes the whole width of the page. At the moment there is a large gap to the right of it. This gap to the right doesn't occur with the main body of the text. This is the how I have it set up so far;

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{}
\date{}
\title{Title}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{Text}
\lfoot{Name}
\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{0.01cm}  of 13}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\usepackage[
top    = 2.50cm,
bottom = 2.50cm,
left   = 2cm,
right  = 2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
Text
\newpage
Next page
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You need to load the `fncyhdr` package and associated code *after* changing the `\marginpar...` length parameters and loading the `geometry` package.

Comment: Also the `\margin...` parameters should be set through `geometry`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Don't set page dimensions manually if you are using `geometry` because `geometry` needs to know what is going on in order to calculate things correctly. So tell `geometry` about them rather than changing them independently. You probably want to use something font-sensitive in place of `0.01cm` in the right foot. Just putting `\thepage\ of 13` would get you a regular space.

Comment: @Mico Tidying up as the original comments have evaporated by now. (Maybe TeX SE should have comments where you can set an auto-destruct mechanism with a timer...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{}
\date{}
\title{Title}
\usepackage[
  top    = 2.50cm,% presumably you don't want it to be 0pt as well?
  bottom = 2.50cm,
  left   = 2cm,
  right  = 2cm,
  marginparsep = 0pt,
  marginparwidth=0pt,
  showframe,% just to show what is happening
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{Text}
\lfoot{Name}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\  of 13}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \thispagestyle{fancy}
  Text
  \newpage
  Next page
\end{document}
```

Note that the frames are just to show what is happening. Remove the `showframe` option to eliminate them.

[image: centred footer]